# How to configure Catfish desktop search tool?

Tags: configuration, search

**Catfish** is my preferred desktop search tool. But by default it uses "**find**" and searches in the "catfish" directory. I want it to use "**locate**" and search in "**home**".

How do I change that? I already searched for a configuration file but didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Catfish** is a GTK+ search utility written in python. It's search is powered by **find** and **locate**, with search suggestions provided by **zeitgeist**.

**`locate`** is now the default search engine in **Catfish 0.4.0.2** version.

You can also just easily change the default directory where Catfish will search by clicking on the "look-in" drop-down box.

[image]

For detailed features, see:

http://twotoasts.de/index.php/category/4-catfish/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. So it seems I need to build version 0.4.0.1 (I have 0.3.2 from the repos). The installation instructions that come with the new version are pretty clear to understand, but since I never compiled anything for stability reasons: Are there any risks for destabilizing my system (I run 12.04 LTS)?

Comment: Is it possible to actually do anything with the results???
I cant believe that once the files are found I cant do anything to all of them - I can delete them one by one !!!
Please do figure out the command line way of doing it but save the lecture - if I wanted to do it that way I would have even less need for Catfish.

Comment: Trying version 1.4.13 and I can't find a way to make it search by `find`. Catfish finds nothing in my external USB hard drive.